# Selecting a portion of data from a Data grid view c#

Tags: c#, datagridview, datasource

I am trying to select a portion of data from a datagridview with a mouse drag which is getting information from a text file, and then update the datagridview with this selected data.

UPDATE:

Initial error of being unable to clear the grid view is resolved, now when the selected data is trying to be re-entered into the grid this line of text appears in the datagrid where the data should be:
"DataGridViewRow { Index=-1 }"

```
   private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<DataGridViewRow> rowCollection = new List<DataGridViewRow>();
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
        {
            rowCollection.Add(dataGridView1.Rows[row.Index]);
        }

           dataset.Tables[0].Clear();

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in rowCollection)
        {
           // dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
            dataset.Tables[tableName].Rows.Add(row);

        }
    }
```

Here is the initial code for displaying the information in the datagridview:

```
foreach (string row in rows)
            {
                //Adds time to the array
                var items = new List<string> { timeS };
                items.AddRange(row.Split(delimeter.ToArray()));

                speed = Convert.ToDouble(items[2]);
                //converts 'speed' to a double and divides by 10 to display the correct value
                speed = speed / 10;
                items[2] = speed.ToString();
                dataset.Tables[tableName].Rows.Add(items.ToArray());
                //Adds the interval time to Dtime for each row
                Dtime = Dtime.AddSeconds(inter);

            }
            //selects where to display the data
            this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dataset.Tables[0].DefaultView;
        }
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not clear the DataGridView.Rows, because you have specified a datasource.
You must clear the DataSource of the DataGridView.

Instead of

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
```

write :

```
dataset.Tables[0].Clear();
```

**EDIT:**
You have a mistake in your Code ... You can't add a DataGridViewRow in a Table
This code fixes your issue:

```
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in rowCollection)
    {
        DataRow r =  dataset.Tables[tableName].NewRow();
        //
        //write the data in the DataRow and then add the datarow in your           datatable
        dataset.Tables[tableName].Rows.Add(r);

    }
```

Comment: This has fixed the error to do with not clearing the list, but not I am struggling to repopulate it with the selected data from the grid view

Comment: 'List' is throwing the error 'Using the generic type 'Systems.Collections.Generic.List<T>' requires 1 type arguments, I tried setting it as a <string> but it didn't work